# What happens when player-controlled NPCs concede and get taken out?

Tags: combat, fate-core, animal-companions, conceding

Let's say I'm using [Companions](http://www.efpress.net/blog/press.net/2014/12/companions.html), virtually any variation of [Stormcaller](http://fate-srd.com/fate-system-toolkit/stormcallers), or any other way of being in command of NPCs in-game.

How do you handle conceding and getting taken out with player-controlled NPCs in play? This question has 4 elements:

- If you (the PC) get taken out, what happens to your companion? Could you subsequently take actions for it?
- If you (the PC) concede, can you argue that your companion remains in the conflict? Could you subsequently take actions for it?
- Can companions get "taken out" at all? What would that look like?
- If a companion is about to be hit with an undesirable attack, can you concede on its behalf without giving up the encounter for yourself (the PC)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A concession is a freeform agreement between players at the table. As long as the players agree on the terms, any and all of the characters can be subject of the concession.

The GM is a player that routinely controls more than one character, and he can offer a concession involving one or more of them at any point. The same should be true for any other player controlling multiple characters.

And if the players can't agree on the terms of the concession, they should just continue the conflict.

Comment: Is that to say that a player controlling 5 NPCs could theoretically concede for all of them in succession, thus earning 5 Fate Points without even being removed from the encounter? What about being taken out?

Comment: @Robert Trust your players not to do that. If need be, ask "would Gorblaxis the Great Dragoon Smasher really bow out of this fight?" Alternately, keep separate FP pools for NPCs players are plying.

Comment: @Robert, it is justified by having to spend for five characters. By the way, those are secondary PC's, not NPC's.

Comment: Also, characters that get a fate point for a concession are the ones that suffered a consequence during the conflict. And the conceding player receives those FP's at **the end** of the conflict, not in the middle of it.